# What are the implications of multi-tasking in iOS 4.0 for developers?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, multitasking

I just watched [this video](http://www.apple.com/iphone/design/#design-video) from Apple that shows multi-tasking on the new iPhone (running iOS 4.0).  What are the implications of multi-tasking to **developers**?  Include both positives and negatives.

For **example** what happens if the user decides to launch two resource-intensives apps at the same time, one of the apps crashes and progress in a game (for example) is lost.  Should developers be considering this when writing apps for the new OS and phone?

Comment: iOS 4.0 is stil covered by Apple's NDA. The only non-NDA material is today's keynote. The answer you're looking for will have to wait until the official release of the 4.0 SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example what happens if the user
>   decides to launch two
>   resource-intensives apps at the same
>   time, one of the apps crashes and progress in a game (for example) is lost?

One of them will run on foreground. If the system gets thin on resources, it will terminate the one running in background. The application always gets a chance to save its state.